# How to admin login using two tables data in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have 3 tables `users`, `roles` and `permissions`

### users table

[image: users]

### roles

[image: roles]

### permissions

[image: permissions]

In `users` table `user1` is Admin and he has to login when his roleId is 13 in roles table and view is 1 in permissions table. How to write query for this. I have tried something, but it is not working

### Adminmodel.php

```
public function auth($data){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM users
                WHERE email='". $data['email'] . "'
                AND password='". $data['password']."'
                AND roleId=13
                UNION
                SELECT roleId FROM permissions 
                WHERE view=1" ;
                ;

        $query=$this->db->query($sql);
        return $query;
    }
```

### Adminlogin controller.php

```
public function auth(){
        $username=$this->input->post("username");
        $password=md5($this->input->post('password'));
        $data['email']=$username;
        $data['password']=$password;
        $q=$this->Adminmodel->auth($data);
        $result=0;
        $status=0;
        if($q->num_rows()>0){
            $result=$q->row()->status==0?-1:1;
            if($result==1){
                $admindata=array(
                        'cp_adminid'=>$q->row()->userId,
                        'cp_roleid'=>$q->row()->roleId
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($admindata);
                if (!is_dir('private/'.$q->row()->userId)) {
                    $oldmask = umask(0);
                    $q=mkdir('private/' .$q->row()->userId,0777,true);
                    umask($oldmask);
                    copy('public/images/default_user.png','private/'.$q->row()->userId.'/default-profile_pic.png');
                }
                }else{

                }

                //$msg="error occured";
            }

        $data['result']=$result;
        //$res=$this->load->view("user/userhome",$data,true);
        $value=array(
                'result'=>$result,

        );
        echo json_encode($value);
    }
```

Comment: use joins in place of union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JOINS` in place of `UNION`.
`JOINS` are used to define relation between different tables and fetch data based on them.

For your question, this will work.

```
SELECT * FROM users u
JOIN roles r ON r.roleId = u.roleId
JOIN permissions p ON p.roleId = r.roleId
WHERE email='". $data['email'] . "'
AND password='". $data['password']."'
AND r.roleId=13
AND p.view=1
```

Also refer this link for basics of MYSQL JOINS: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: It showing some error like this `<p>Error Number: 1064</p><p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
 to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as p.roleId = r.roleId
     WHERE email='user1@gmail.com'
     AND password='6' at line 3</p><p>SELECT * FROM users u
     JOIN roles r on r.roleId = u.roleId
     JOIN permissions p as p.roleId = r.roleId
     WHERE email='user1@gmail.com'
     AND password='6ad14ba9986e3615423dfca256d04e3f'
     AND r.roleId=13
     WHERE p.view=1</p>`

Comment: I have changed it to ON. Now it shows like `<p>Error Number: 1064</p><p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
 to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE p.view=1' at line 9</p>`

Comment: in place of 'WHERE p.view=1'
make 'AND p.view=1'

Comment: okay query is working but now error in `Adminlogin controller.php` on this line `copy('public/images/default_user.png','private/'.$q->row()->userId.'/default-profile_pic.png');` like `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function row() on a non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ci3\application
\controllers\admin\Adminlogin.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />
`

Comment: You do print_r($q); after this $q=$this->Adminmodel->auth($data);
and see what $q is returning based on that change ur code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135349/discussion-between-kevin-and-naincy).